How to reuse small parsers in `alt` when they cannot `move`?
As an example I want to parse a string that can either be 2 dot-separated words or a single word. Each "word" is a combination of alphanumeric and underscore characters, so I write the word-parser as a closure. In either case I want the parser-function to return a pair of words with one of them potentially being an empty string. There might be a better solution for this specific problem, but I simply want to motivate my problem here.
Writing my parser with nom I stumble upon the following problem: I cannot write my sub-parsers as closures (in order to re-use them), because the closures are moved if I use them multiple times in an alt statement:
fn parse_dot_sep_words_or_word(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, (&str, &str)> {
    let word = recognize(many0(alt((alphanumeric1, tag("_")))));
    let dot_sep_word = separated_pair(word, tag("."), word);

    alt((
        map(word, |single_word| ("", single_word)),
        map(dot_sep_word, |(a,b)| (a,b))
    ))
    (i)
}

This does not work as word gets moved once it is used inside dot_sep_word. Following the instructions of the compiler ("use &mut word") doesn't help either.
The only solution I can use is to write out what word is defined as everytime word is used. But this seems counterintuitive to the advantages nom offers.
What did I miss here? Is there a simple way this can be solved?

You can wrap word in a 'factory' closure: let word = || recognize( /* ... */ );, and call it every time you need it with word(). This will create a 'fresh' value every time.

In your case defining word as function would be the simplest solution.

Thank you! I didn't even know that about closures ( the ()-part). I'll try this.

One option is to simply make word a function instead of a closure.
fn word(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    recognize(many0(alt((alphanumeric1, tag("_")))))(i)
}

fn parse_dot_sep_words_or_word(i: &str) -> IResult<&str, (&str, &str)> {
    let dot_sep_word = separated_pair(word, tag("."), word);

    alt((
        map(word, |single_word| ("", single_word)),
        map(dot_sep_word, |(a, b)| (a, b)),
    ))(i)
}


Thank you! I also used it like this, but thought maybe I could avoid using an extra function. But maybe in the long run this is cleaner anyway. Thank you!

It's a bit surprising, but recognize returns a impl FnMut instead of the more flexible impl Fn<..> but you can create a Fn closure that does the same thing:
    let word = |s| recognize(many0(alt((alphanumeric1, tag("_")))))(s);

Since that doesn't capture any environment this closure implements Copy so your other code works without any changes.
